# How to concat 2 fields in query

Tags: mysql

I have a native query:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE (" +
            "(lower(p.name) like concat('%',:source,'%'))" +
            "OR (lower(p.surname) like concat('%',:source,'%'))" +
            "OR (lower(p.email) like concat('%',:source,'%'))" +
            "OR (lower(p.phone) like concat('%',:source,'%')))")
    Page<Person> search(@Param("source") String source, Pageable pageable);
```

And it allows me to search for name/surname etc. 
Although I would like to search for name AND surname in browser as well (with space).

I tried adding

```
"(lower(p.name) like concat('%',:source,'%') AND (lower(p.surname) like concat('%',:source,'%')))" +
            "OR (lower(p.name) like concat('%',:source,'%'))" +
```

etc...

But it is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: Try concatenate wild cards (`%`) during param binding `@Param("source")` instead of query

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
concat(p.name, ' ', p.surname) like concat('%', :source, '‰')
```

Which will only work if both are pretty close and the space matches exactly. You may also be able to find a way to  use rlike with word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to work out if you have the Concat in the right place - for example, if Source='Joe Bloggs', and you are looking for p.name='Joe' and p.Surname='Bloggs', then don't you want`(concat(p.name, ' ', p.surname') LIKE concat('%', :source:, '%'))`to evaluate as`'Joe Bloggs' LIKE '%Joe Bloggs%'`

Or am I getting confused?